# IOException: Sharing violation on path

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, io

here is my code to create a .dat file or append text to it:

```
public static void saveGameAnalyseData(GameAnalyseData gameAnalyseData)
{
    Debug.Log(JsonUtility.ToJson(gameAnalyseData) + " " + Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + gameAnalyseData.gameID + ".dat");

    if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + gameAnalyseData.gameID + ".dat"))
    {
        File.AppendAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + gameAnalyseData.gameID + ".dat", JsonUtility.ToJson(gameAnalyseData) + Environment.NewLine);
    }
    else
    {
       File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + gameAnalyseData.gameID + ".dat");
        if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + gameAnalyseData.gameID + ".dat"))
        {
            File.AppendAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + gameAnalyseData.gameID + ".dat", JsonUtility.ToJson(gameAnalyseData) + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```

But i get

> IOException: Sharing violation on path
>   on the second  `File.AppendAllText` call...

i also tried this code:

```
    if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + gameAnalyseData.gameID + ".dat"))
    {
        File.AppendAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + gameAnalyseData.gameID + ".dat", JsonUtility.ToJson(gameAnalyseData) + Environment.NewLine);
    }
    else
    {
       File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + gameAnalyseData.gameID + ".dat");
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + gameAnalyseData.gameID + ".dat");
        sw.WriteLine(JsonUtility.ToJson(gameAnalyseData) + Environment.NewLine);
        // close the stream
        sw.Close();
    }
```

but i get same error on this line:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + gameAnalyseData.gameID + ".dat");
```

**PS:** I should mention that when the file exists, it append the text to it correctly, the problem is when creating the file and writing to it for the first time

Comment: File.Create opens the file and returns a FileStream (you can pass it to the StreamWriter constructor). As it is now, your StreamWriter is unable to open the file because you have it open by the File.Create. Besides this is all unnecessary. File.AppendAllText creates the file if it doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just replace all of your code with just this line of code:

```
File.AppendAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + gameAnalyseData.gameID + ".dat", JsonUtility.ToJson(gameAnalyseData) + Environment.NewLine);
```

Because the `AppendAllText` method opens a file, appends the specified string to the file, and then closes the file, if the file doesn't exist, this method creates a file, writes the specified string to the file then closes the file.

Anyway if you want to use your own code, everywhere that you use `File.Create(filePath);` Replace with this code, `File.Create(filename).Close();` . Because `File.Create(filePath)` creates or overwrite a file in a specified path and then return an open `FileStream` object to that file. If you want, you can use this `FileStream` object to work with your file, if you don't want so you should close it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was Anti-Virus, with intensive writing to a file, Anti-Virus began to scan the file and at that moment there was a problem with writing to the file.